# nouislider custom steps with single drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, nouislider

I try to add custom steps to [nouislider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) but with no luck.

**The slider moves from 500 to 10000 and misses 1000.**

```
$("#nouislider").noUiSlider({
    start: 500,
    snap: true,
    range: {
        'min': [500],
        '1000': [1000],
        'max': [10000],
    },
 });
```

**Did not work, same thing**

```
$("#nouislider").noUiSlider({
    start: 500,
    snap: true,
    range: {
        'min': 500,
        '1000': 1000,
        'max': 10000,
    },
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keys` in the `range` option indicate where you want the value to be on the range. If you want it half-way:

```
$("#nouislider").noUiSlider({
    start: 500,
    snap: true,
    range: {
        'min': 500,
        '50%': 1000, // Note the percentage indicated here.
        'max': 10000
    }
});
```